# Cypher group by subquery syntax

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregation

I need to do an aggregation on an aggregation in Cypher on Neo4j;

```
match (
  match (w:words) 
  return distinct k.word as word, count(w) as count, count(distinct w.id) as id
  ) as a
return distinct id, count(word), sum(count);
```

Is this possible, google suggests not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using [`with`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_with):

```
match (w:words)
with distinct w.word as word, count(w) as count, count(distinct w.id) as id
return distinct id, count(word), sum(count);
```